# How to cite a new journal in abbreviation form which is not found in existing abbreviation list?

Tags: citations, paper-submission, ieee

Recently, I want to submitted a paper to IEEE, I encounter a problem when I want to cite a paper from a new journal, for example, [*Systems Science & Control Engineering*](http://www.tandfonline.com/loi/tssc20#.VNmJ9tLF8VQ) . According to IEEE standard, all papers submitted should have the abbreviation form of journal name in reference, however, I can not find the abbreviation form for the journal I want to cite. How to solve this problem?

I tried this abbreviation database [JabRef/reference-abbreviations](https://github.com/JabRef/reference-abbreviations/tree/master/journals) and not found.

Comment: You could write the journal and ask them. They should know and it's in their interest to have a well-defined abbreviation.

Comment: @fileunderwater I had twittered their office twitter, hopefully, we will find answer soon. Besides, my best guess would be `Syst. Sci. Control Eng.` based on the abbreviation pattern appeared on ` JabRef/reference-abbreviations `.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a list of journal abbreviations issued by ISI (now Clarivate) where official abbreviations are found. There are many places where the list is found but the best updated will likely be the one at [Web of Science](https://images.webofknowledge.com/images/help/WOS/A_abrvjt.html). Your journal is not listed here as far as I can see but abbreviations follow certain guidelines so it would not be difficult to "guess" what abbreviation should be suitable. My guess will be *Syst. Sci. Contr. Eng.* based on other existing abbreviations including the words that make up the title.

Note, however, that this is still not the formal abbreviation and I would add a note to the fact to the editor when submitting the manuscript so the journal can decide what to print based on what you have provided. It is possible that the copy-editing will catch this as well but declaring your actions will always help editors in their work and will be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much, hopefully, we can find the official one. Science I can't the official one, if it's okay to cite it in full name instead of abbreviation?

Comment: Besides, I found the abbreviation list in [Web of Science(WOS)](http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOK46/help/WOS/S_abrvjt.html)  is not compatible with the abbreviation list in IEEE, for example the journal `IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON AUTOMATIC CONTROL`, in WOS it has `IEEE T AUTOMAT CONTR`, while IEEE gives `IEEE Trans AUTOMAT CONTR`

Comment: I found a pattern, if a journal is IEEE's, the `control` is the title should be abbreviated as `contr`, otherwise, `control` is not abbreviated. Hence, my best guess would be `Syst. Sci. Control Eng.` :)